# JBoss user permissions

Tags: linux, jboss, permissions, centos, activemq-classic

I've upgraded from JBoss EAP 6.2.0GA to 6.3.0GA, and run into this problem after installing ActiveMQ as an embedded module. The same configuration is working on my Windows computer, so I believe it is some sort of CentOS permissions issue.

```
INFO [org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker] (Starting ActiveMQ Broker) Database activemq-data/kahadb/lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory 'activemq-data/kahadb'
```

Note that it has no problem writing logs or anything.  It's just this damn activemq related permission.

**The issue only occurs if I run it as a service.**
i.e. 
service jboss-as start

If I run bin/standalone.sh & it works fine.

I've given the jboss.jboss user ownership over everything related to JBoss now, and chmod is 755 for everything.  (There's a lot of confusing info about jboss:jboss or jboss.jboss to refer to the user in the jboss group.  But neither works.)

```
   chown -fR jboss.jboss /usr/share/jboss-eap-6.3/
   chown jboss.jboss /usr/share/jboss-as
   chown jboss.jboss /etc/init.d/jboss-as
   chown jboss.jboss /etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf
```

I've done

```
ln -s -T /usr/share/jboss-eap-6.3 /usr/share/jboss-as
ln -s -T /usr/share/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh /etc/init.d/jboss-as
ln -s -T /usr/share/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/init.d/jboss-as.conf /etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf
```

My  mgmt-groups.properties has:

```
jboss=jboss, admin, SuperUser
```

not that I know particularly how this helps.

My mgmt-users.properties has:

```
jboss=6ca43af9943e59f1563a1ff04472a8f9
```

suggesting that add-user.sh did something.

I haven't edited standalone.xml with regards to security or permissions.

```
grep 'jboss' /etc/group
```

shows:

```
jboss:x:502:
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, worked it out from turning on the DEBUG logs and stepping through.

The difference is that when you do service X start, it is running it from /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory, instead of when you do it directly, where it's running it from the /bin/ directory.

```
     [org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService] (Starting ActiveMQ Broker) Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/etc/rc.d/init.d/activemq-data/kahadb]
ESC[0mESC[0m13:31:46,998 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker] (Starting ActiveMQ Broker) Database activemq-data/kahadb/lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory 'activemq-data/kahadb'
```

So this worked:

```
chown -R jboss.jboss /etc/rc.d/init.d/
chmod -R 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a cleanest solution

Comment: well if you come up with something better, let me know.  It's run fine since this fix.